# Sorting a subclass of STL list

Tags: c++, list, sorting, c++11, stl

Consider a templated class that I've created called `myList`, it basically extends the `std::list` object provided in the C++ STL. I've overridden a few functions such as `size()`, `front()` and `back()` but have not touched the `sort()` function that is provided with `std::list`.

Basically, I want to be able to sort `myList`, consider my decorator implementation:

```
#import "myList.h"

template <typename T>
class myListDecorator : public myList<T> {

public:
    myListDecorator() : m_list(myList<T>()){}

    myListDecorator(const myList<T> &my_list) {
        m_list = my_list.sort();
    }

private:
    myList<T> m_list;

};
```

Whenever I create a `myList` (in these case using objects of type `double`) I get the following error:

`Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const myList<double>' to 'std::list<double, std::allocator<double>>' for object argument`.

Do I have to override the `sort()` function in `myList` and implement my own sort for this to work?

**EDIT:**

A few of the comments pointed out how confusing it was having effectively two `myList` objects in this class. I've updated my code to be more 'correct'/'best practice'. It now does what I intended it to do and is much tidier:

```
#include "myList.h"

template <typename T>
class myListDecorator : public myList<T> {

public:
    myListDecorator() : myList<T>(myList<T>()){}

    myListDecorator(const myList<T> &my_list) : myList<T>(my_list){
        this->sort();
    }
};
```

Comment: Publicly inheriting standard containers is considered bad practice.

Comment: Why did you publicly inherit from `std::list` instead of making `std::list` a member of `myListDecorator`?

Comment: Indeed, good question. If you inherit from `myList` and also have a `myList` member, you have *two* lists in `myListDecorator`. That's going to be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for raising this - of course! I'll update my question with some new code that is more correct. Though I didn't end up using your answer @GregHewgill, I'll accept as it does answer the original question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `my_list` is `const`. The `sort()` member function modifies the list in place, and cannot do that with a constant list. (Note that the return type of `sort()` is `void`.)

You should be able to:

```
myListDecorator(const myList<T> &my_list): m_list(my_list) {
    m_list.sort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your are trying to cast a const myList to a non-const type.
BTW, '#import' is not a standard C/C++ preprocessor statement.